# Why can't I store a PictureBox^ in a std::vector?

Tags: winforms, vector, c++-cli, containers, picturebox

For a collision system that I'm building I need to have a vector of images:

```
vector<PictureBox^> Wall{ Player1,Wall_1,Wall_2 };
```

This is how I have instantiated the vector, this does not compile successfully.

```
vector<PictureBox^> Wall;
```

You can instantiate the vector like this perfectly fine since nothing is being added to it.

And when I try to compile the program with the first instantiation these are some of the errors I get...
[image]

I have tried pretty much all standard compliant containers such as list and deque, but to no prevail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot mix standard C++ with C++/CLI, as their types have special requirements (like their pointers are garbage collected). You'll have to use their specific containers if you want to store gc-ed pointers in it.

For example, a general purpose array is `List`:

```
List<PictureBox^>^ list = gcnew List<PictureBox^>();
```

Comment: Ahh I see. Thanks for the reply. However I still have a problem. List is undefined. Am I just missing a header?

Comment: @DEFAULT Don't think so. But it's in the `Systems::Collections::Generic` namespace, so you might want to add a using declaration for it.